# Change in cache-manifest file

Tags: html

Whenever there is a change in cache-manifest file i.e. a resource is changed, do I need to redeploy my web application on server or can I update the files dynamically i.e. is there any way to update the files dynamically when the server is running.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about the HTML5 cache manifest for an offline web application -- when you modify the cache-manifest file, all of the assets listed in the manifest are re-downloaded to the client browser when they access it next.  There is no way to selectively update individual files in the cache.  It's all or nothing unfortunately.

Also, I've found the the file containing the  is automatically cached even if it's not listed in the manifest.  When the manifest changes, this file is replaced, but only after it's loaded... so it effectively requires an additional refresh to see the changes.  I've seen various JavaScript hacks to force a reload if the cache updates.

I wrote a fairly extensive blog post on html5 app cache and the various aspects of the manifest file at http://gregsramblings.com/2012/05/28/html5-application-cache-how-to/

Comment: My question is at web server side if I update the cache-manifest file while server is running, does my html5 application reloads the resources? or does it require a web application re start? I guess it will hot deploy on tomcat..

Comment: It will only reload the resources if the cache manifest file is check again (any HTML file with the manifest reference is loaded).